# Facing issue with bind on rhel 6.4

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, rhel6

As per the link (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid
), I followed the same steps to configure DNS/bind on my servers (RHEL 6.4).

Configuration is as below. unfortunately, its failed. please help me to rectify the issue and resolve it.

Configuring DNS with BIND
If you use BIND for your on-premises DNS resolution, you can configure it to make use of response policy zones (RPZ). Here is an example BIND configuration:

Add the following lines to /etc/bind/named.conf:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
```

Add the following lines to /etc/bind/named.conf.options:

```
options {
  directory "/var/cache/bind";


dnssec-validation no;



auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC 1035
  listen-on-v6 { any; };
  listen-on { any; };
};
```

Add the following lines to /etc/bind/named.conf.local:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";


allow-query { any;};



response-policy { zone "googleapis.zone"; };



zone "googleapis.zone" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db.googleapis.zone";
  allow-query {none;};
};
```

Add the following lines to /etc/bind/db.googleapis.zone:

```
$TTL 1H
@                       SOA LOCALHOST. noreply.localhost(1 1h 15m 30d 2h)
                        NS  LOCALHOST.


*.googleapis.com CNAME restricted.googleapis.com.
restricted.googleapis.com CNAME rpz-passthru.
```

Comment: What is failing? What error message or configuration message are you getting? Show the actual files that you configured, the tests that you are running, etc. in your question. Don't show examples, show actual files.